# Rails: nested resources and routing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I've got a `Template` model, and a `Doc` model. They're nested resources, with the `Templates` being the parent, thus:

```
resources :templates do
  get "/documents/lock/:id" => "docs#lock", :as => :lock_doc
  get "/documents/unlock/:id" => "docs#unlock", :as => :unlock_doc
  get "/documents/pdf/:id" => "docs#pdf", :as => :pdf_doc
  resources :docs, :path => :documents
end
```

That part, I think, all works fine. When I try to submit the form for creating a `doc` the record exists but I get routing errors, thus:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"docs", :template_id=>nil, :id=>#<Doc id: 2, user_id: "admin", cover: "1209hpnl", message: "The world economic outlook is improving, albeit slo...", created_at: "2013-01-07 03:54:05", updated_at: "2013-01-07 03:54:05", issue_code: "1209hpnl", title: "January 2013", locked: nil, retired: "active", template: nil>}):
app/controllers/docs_controller.rb:134:in `block (2 levels) in create'
app/controllers/docs_controller.rb:132:in `create'
```

The lines correspond to the `create` method:

```
def create
  @doc = Doc.new(params[:doc])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @doc.save
      format.html { redirect_to share_url(@doc), notice: "Saved. You may from here #{view_context.link_to('edit', edit_template_doc_url(@doc))} it further, #{view_context.link_to('finalise', template_lock_doc_url(@doc))} it, or return #{view_context.link_to('home', root_url)}.".html_safe }
      format.json { render json: @doc, status: :created, location: @doc }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @doc.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I think the problem lies somewhere in here, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Cheers for any help!

EDIT: with `rake routes`

```
    template_lock_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/lock/:id(.:format)   docs#lock
  template_unlock_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/unlock/:id(.:format) docs#unlock
     template_pdf_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/pdf/:id(.:format)    docs#pdf
        template_docs GET    /templates/:template_id/documents(.:format)            docs#index
                      POST   /templates/:template_id/documents(.:format)            docs#create
     new_template_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/new(.:format)        docs#new
    edit_template_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/:id/edit(.:format)   docs#edit
         template_doc GET    /templates/:template_id/documents/:id(.:format)        docs#show
                      PUT    /templates/:template_id/documents/:id(.:format)        docs#update
                      DELETE /templates/:template_id/documents/:id(.:format)        docs#destroy
            templates GET    /templates(.:format)                                   templates#index
                      POST   /templates(.:format)                                   templates#create
         new_template GET    /templates/new(.:format)                               templates#new
        edit_template GET    /templates/:id/edit(.:format)                          templates#edit
             template GET    /templates/:id(.:format)                               templates#show
                      PUT    /templates/:id(.:format)                               templates#update
                      DELETE /templates/:id(.:format)                               templates#destroy
```

Comment: `rake routes` is your friend. Chances are the routes aren't what you think they are.

Comment: I just updated with relevant routes raked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your call to `edit_template_doc_url(@doc)` inside the notice string. You need to supply the template as well, like this:

```
edit_template_doc_url(params[:template_id], @doc)
```

Comment: That didn't work. I adjusted the other edit buttons in the view to match that, too, and nothing.

Comment: Oh, it wouldn't be `edit_template_doc_url(params[:template_id], @doc)` in the view, would it? It'd be something like `edit_template_doc_path(@doc.template_id, @doc)`, yeah? I just don't know how to refer to the parent's `ID` from there.

Comment: Yes, it should probably be `@doc.template_id` whenever you use that path helper. I just didn't know if that was the association since you didn't use `@doc = @template.docs.build(params[:doc])` in your create action.